# Upsert object with not all its properties filled in

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

From a UI of lwc component:

- edit an object
- remove the value of a lookup field
- click on "Save"

At this point, the object is sent back to an apex method.
When debugging this method, only the properties filled in are received.
i.e: `object.Name = 'ABCDE', object.Custom__c = 'XYZ'` 
But since I remove the country, object.Country is not received.

How to set object.country to get it in the Apex method ?
In the js side `save()`, I've tried `object['Country'] = undefined;`  , `object['Country'] = null;`  and `object['Country'] = "";`

Comment: When you debug in js before removing country like console.log(this.object); what do you receive? Also you can try in js something like this.object.country(replace country with exactly the name of the field as js is case-sensitive)

Comment: If you've declared your object as an object type, for example:

    sObject__c object = new sObject__c();

then you should be able to treat it like a normal object:

    object.Country = null;

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess a cache issue because right now `object['Country'] = null;`  works fine